# Possible bug in powershell replace, or am I doing it wrong?

Tags: regex, powershell, backreference

I am doing regexps on some data and if $_ is in the "replace" section I get the contents as well.  I have tried various things for $replace but appear to be unable to stop this behavior.  I also tried [regex]::escape() however that ends up doing the same thing, just with escape chars.

I need to be able to tolerate $_ in the replace.  I could make it something else and do a fixup later but that is ugly and I would rather avoid it.

Lastly if $replace='$anythingelse' it appears to function as expected, only $_ appears to cause this problem.  If all parsing could be disabled that would work as well.

The script:

> ```
>  $contents = 'foo'
>  $replace = '$_ bar'
>  $final = $contents -replace 'oo', $replace
>  Write-Output "Contents: $contents"
>  Write-Output "Replace: $replace"
>  Write-Output "Final: $final"
> ```

The output:

> ```
>  Contents: foo
>  Replace: $_ bar
>  Final: ffoo bar
> ```

System: Windows 7, PSH 2, 64bit

So am I doing something wrong or is this genuinely a bug?

**EDIT 6/29:**

I did a replace so I could do the replace.  This is silly and there should be a way to disable parsing (which would make it run slightly faster too).

> ```
>  $contents = 'foo'
>  $replace = '$_ bar'
>  **$rep = $replace -replace '\$','$$$'**
>  $final = $contents -replace 'oo', $rep
>  Write-Output "Contents: $contents"
>  Write-Output "Replace: $replace"
>  Write-Output "Final: $final"
> ```

Output

> ```
>  Contents: foo
>  Replace: $_ bar
>  Final: f$_ bar
> ```

Comment: Just so I'm clear, your replace text is literally a dollar-sign followed by an underscore?  IOW - you're not trying to do something with the powershell pipeline variable?

Comment: Correct.  I want the output to be

Final: f$_ bar

Comment: Well that's interesting.  It seems like a bug.  I tried other commands like `write-output '$_ bar'` that work as expected.  So, it seems like a bug to me.  Of course, as soon as I say that, someone far more clever than me will come along and show us that it isn't.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that "$_" in a replacement string represents the entire input string. If you want a literal dollar sign, you need to escape it using $$:

```
$replace = '$$_ bar'
```

See the [substitutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx) page on msdn for details!

**EDIT to address question edits 29/6**

If all you want is a basic string replacement without any regex at all, just use the standard string replacement instead of `-replace`:

```
$final = $contents.replace('oo', $replace)
```

Comment: That wont work.  I guess powershell is just not capable of doing this (why I have written a perl script).

in the real script $replace and $contents come from somewhere else external to the script, the only way to escape $_ would be to do a replace on it, which is something I said I could do but would rather avoid because its ugly.

Comment: @user1489948 Caon you more specific when you say 'come from somewhere else external to the script'. How/where the powershell script take this values?

Answer (score 0):

I reached to do it using:

```
`$$`_
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).